# Intellisence not working in visual studio code for Node.js

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I installed the current Node.js and created a folder. I opened the folder with visual studio code. I started to type the following code

```
 const EventEmitter = require('events');
 const emitter = new EventEmitter();

 emitter.  -- This does not give me the intellisence.
```

[image]

How can I get the intellisence so I can use the methods within this class? I have been trying this for some time and no luck. Do I need to install something else?

Comment: use the class from the imported module e.g. `require("events").EventEmitter`. intellisense works with this. from types file, events module exports the namespace and so you need to access the class within. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/events.d.ts

Comment: This works for me. Thanks. So this changed? Most videos online do not have it like this

Comment: not sure. nodejs seems to work with both. vscode only works with this. node's official doc also doesn't say this but tutorials like w3schools, tutorialsteacher etc use the suggested snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install nodejs types

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

Comment: I installed it and it is still the same thing. No changes. I still don't get the intellisence.

Comment: is your js code file location and node_modules in same folder? if no you can also install the types globally `npm install -g @types/node`

Comment: Yes it is. They are in the same location

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure but I tested it on my vscode, using `require` it does not work but when I user `import` which I use usually it works just fine, so maybe trying `import { EventEmitter } from 'events'` so the case seems as what @gp said.